# Show that this function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Suppose that $F : A \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic on an open set $A \subset \mathbb{C}$. Show that $$f : A \to \mathbb{C}$$

$$z \mapsto \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
             \frac{F(z)-F(z_0)}{z-z_0} & \mbox{if $z \neq z_0$};\\
             F'(z) & \mbox{ if $z = z_0$}.\end{array} \right.$$

is holomorphic on $A$, where $z_0 \in A$. I'm pretty sure there's an easy trick to this, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f$ is holomorphic in $A\setminus \{z_0\}.$ So $f$ has an isolated singularity at $z_0.$ When is an isolated singularity removable?

Answer (score 0):

Of course $f$ is holomorphic at all points $z\in A$, $z\ne z_0$.

Let's look at $z_0$. Expand $F$ in a power series around $z_0$
$$
F(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_n(z-z_0)^n
$$
Then, for $z$ in a punctured neighborhood of $z_0$, you have
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_{n+1}(z-z_0)^n
$$
and the series in the right-hand side also converges for $z=z_0$ to $a_1=F'(z_0)=f(z_0)$.

> Since $f$ admits a power series representation in a neighborhood of $z_0$, it is holomorphic at $z_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $F$ is holomorphic around $z_0$, then $F(z) = \sum \limits _{n \ge 0} a_n (z-z_0)^n$, therefore when $z \ne z_0$ it is clear that $$f(z) = \frac {F(z) - F(z_0)} {z - z_0} = \frac {\sum \limits _{n \ge 0} a_n (z-z_0)^n - a_0} {z - z_0} = \sum \limits _{n \ge 1} a_n (z-z_0)^{n-1} .$$

Note that according to the above, $\lim \limits _{z \to z_0} f(z) = a_1$, which is exactly $F'(z_0)$ which, in turn, is $f(z_0)$, therefore $\lim \limits _{z \to z_0} f(z) = f(z_0)$, so $f$ is continuous in $z_0$; since it is continuous on $A \setminus \{z_0\}$ too, being even holomorphic (as a quotient of holomorphic functions), by [Riemann's theorem about removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem), $f$ will be holomorphic on the whole of $A$.